# How to port in.mpathd from Solaris to Linux?

Tags: linux, solaris, porting

How to use `in.mpathd` command in solaris(by using which options)??

Comment: "How to port in.mpathd" (the title) sounds like a very vague programming question.   "How to use in.mpathd command in solaris" is a question best suited for another site, such as serverfault.com or just reading the docs on docs.sun.com, but doesn't sound anything like the title, nor have any relationship to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what exactly you are looking for but in any case, in.mpathd options are set in /etc/default/mpathd.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the manpage of in.mpathd, I would use OpenAIS-Corosync on Linux.